# NuGet package for Azure DevOps Feed and Package managment

Tags: .net, azure-devops, nuget, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there any .NET client for Feed and Artifact Packages managment available as NuGet package?

Artifacts Azure DevOps REST API docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details/get%20packages?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any .NET client for Feed and Artifact Packages managment available as NuGet package?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such .NET client for Feed and Artifact Packages managment available as **NuGet package**.

When you check the document [.NET client libraries for Azure DevOps and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops), we could get the REST packages, but none of them for Feed and Artifact Packages managment.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.